# How to get distinct results out of two tables with explode?

Tags: php, mysql, select, distinct, explode

I need your help. Here is an example:

Table A

```
id | colors
-------------------------
1  | green
2  | green, blue, red
3  | blue, red
```

Table B

```
id | colors | name
--------------------------
1  | green  | Apple
2  | blue   | Water
3  | red    | Fire
4  | yellow | Sun
```

In PHP I try to select distinct the names of table B, if the color is exist in table A. How can I do that?

Comment: How can you do this in SQL or in PHP?

Comment: I try to do it in php

Answer (score 1):

You could use  find_in_set  and check for result > 0

```
select distinct a.* 
from tableB b
inner join tableA a on  find_in_set(b.colors, a.colors) >0
```

and for obtain the result you could

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT b.name. b.colors 
    FROM b INNER JOIN a ON find_in_set(b.colors, a.colors) >0";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo $rows["name"]; 
    echo $rows["colors"]; 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Works this version also in php? Because I need it there :S

Comment: why using PHP when  you can resolve the problem just using a query ..   ???  this solution with a simple query avoid iteration for a find in array in PHP  .. is more simple and more fast

Comment: You mean like: `$sql="SELECT DISTINCT name FROM b INNER JOIN a ON find_in_set(b.colors, a.colors) >0"; $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql); while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { echo $rows["name"]; }` ?

Comment: answer  updated .. with colors too

Comment: I'v tried but still can't get any results. I don't need the colors, just the names. Is here maybe the problem?

Comment: I had a false collation in the MySQL Database. Now I get a result but only the first and not all. Do you've again a tipp for me?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM a, b WHERE CONCAT(",", a.colors, ",") REGEXP (b.colors)` was the solution, anyway thank you